# How did I superheat my pasta water?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

Last week I had an incident in the kitchen where I almost scolded my face with hot water.

What happened:

I was boiling some water in one pan and a sauce with veggies and meats in another next to it.
After a while I noticed that my water still had no movement or bubbles at all.
Finding it a bit odd, I waited a bit longer.
Suddenly this huge geyser of water shot in the air, at least 50cm above the pan.
With my fortunate impeccable reaction time I dodged almost all of it and turned off the gas.

I finished cooking by added some oil and stirring the water regularly till visually boiling and cooked the pasta without any issue.

The 2l used saucepan was dishwasher clean, probably had multiple spots of residue (calcium and salts from previous use and dishwasher use, right?).
It was filled for about half or 2/3 with tap water.
The pan was on a gas stove, medium-high heat with no lid.

The only thing different from any other time: it was a cold stormy day and I noticed there was bad ventilation in the kitchen. I opened the windows a bit for a healthy amount of fresh air. The yellow flames I noticed went away. This was 10+mins before the incident, when I started. I would say at start, it was 18°C with 25% humidity inside the kitchen, warming up and humidify quickly before I opened the windows.

The geyser was basically the whole (exact) middle circle shooting up in the air, leaving the outer ring undisturbed. Before this, there was no visible movement or sound at all.

What dangerous experiment took place here?

I don't believe the tap water is *that* clean or the surface of the pan *that* smooth in a way it's free of nucleation sites.
Something with pressure or an unfortunate combination of above?

Comment: Water doesn't like start boiling from surfaces that it doesn't wet. Was your saucepan well wettable by water?

Comment: Even with all the "imperfections" there is still a probability of the water super-heating which it obviously did in your case.

Comment: After a handwash, it shows perfect wettability. Could check again after the same dishwasher cycle.

Comment: "Scold[ing]" your face by scalding it :-) .   I bet you can't repeat this experiment, but it sure sounds like a case of extreme superheating, for whatever reasons of random behaviors.   BTW, the yellow flames were more likely due to burning off some residue (or water) on the outside of the saucepan.  The oxygen level in your kitchen won't change measurably by opening/closing windows.